# New to programming. Why does my Python code work EXCEPT in this one situation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to programming and have been using Codecademy for the time being to teach myself Python. Today, I started on my first off-platform project, and my code seemed to work perfectly, until I encountered one situation.

So here is the project: You're talking to a friend and sending encoded messages. The messages are coded by shifting the letters down the alphabet a few places depending on the offset. For example, if we're using an offset of 3, "hello" would be encoded as "ebiil", and likewise "ebiil" would be decoded as "hello". In this example, "a" would wrap back around and be encoded as "x". I wrote the following function to decode messages:

```
message = "xuo jxuhu! jxyi yi qd unqcfbu ev q squiqh syfxuh. muhu oek qrbu je tusetu yj? y xefu ie! iudt cu q cuiiqwu rqsa myjx jxu iqcu evviuj!"
offset = 10

def decoder(message, offset):
    decoded_message = ""
    for char in message:
        if char in alphabet:
            
            #i = The decoded index of the character.
            #i2 = Index once wrapped back around.
            
            i = alphabet.find(char)+offset
            if i < len(alphabet):
                decoded_message += alphabet[i]
            else:
                i2 = offset-(26%alphabet.find(char))
                decoded_message += alphabet[i2]
        else:
            decoded_message += char
    return decoded_message

print(decoder(message,offset))
```

Everything was working fine, until I got to a new step that required me to decode a message using a different offset. I used the `decoder` function, changed `offset` to 14, used `message = "bqdradyuzs ygxfubxq omqemd oubtqde fa oapq kagd yqeemsqe ue qhqz yadq eqogdq!"`, and it printed `performing multiple cmesmr ciphers to code your messmges is even more secure!`. For whatever reason, in this scenario my code is not recognizing that "m" should be changed to "a", and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or what I'm not seeing here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `alphabet` defined? Please make your code a self-contained [mcve].

Comment: I originally had ```alphabet``` defined, but I realized python automatically recognizes it and I didn't have to define it, so I took it out. Regardless, I added it back in underneath ```offset```, so outside the function, and it still gives me the same result.

Comment: "I originally had alphabet defined, but I realized python automatically recognizes it and I didn't have to define it, so I took it out." - but Python *doesn't* automatically recognize `alphabet`. You've got something else going on - maybe you're running this in an interactive session that already had a bunch of stuff defined, or you're not showing us the whole file.

Comment: a is (suspiciously!) the first letter of the alphabet, so this sounds like a simple off-by-one error when you check whether the substitution would wrap around to the beginning.

Comment: I used `from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet` and it seems to work.

Comment: Do away with all that complicated `i` and `i2` business.  You only need one calculation: `decoded_message += alphabet[(alphabet.find(char)+offset)%26]`

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```py
i2 = offset-(26%alphabet.find(char))
```

You're not really accomplishing much. If `char` is at index 2, then `i2` will be `offset`, and if `char` is at index `3`, then `i2` will be at `offset - 2`, and it is very strange. Instead, just take the already existing `i` and take it mod the length of the alphabet, and you can get rid of the if statement entirely:

```py
i = alphabet.find(char) + offset
decoded_message += alphabet[i % len(alphabet)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```py
i2 = offset-(26%alphabet.find(char))
```

is calculating 26 modulo the position of the letter in the alphabet. This doesn't make sense. You would generally want `alphabet.find(char) % 26`. Or `alphabet.find(char) % len(alphabet)` if you want to be more verbose.

Substracting that to the offset is also peculiar. You seem to be working backwards.

I would simply replace the block inside with:

```py
i = alphabet.find(char)+offset
if i < 0:
   i += len(alphabet)
i = i % len(alphabet)
decoded_message += alphabet[i]
```

Then you can simply change the sign for encoding or decoding.

Also note that the else branch of your encoder function (now in the history) is exactly the same as the main one.

PS: I'm sure to have seen a line `i2 = alphabet.find(char)-10` which is not even in the history, it changed to `i2 = alphabet.find(char)-offset`, probably hidden by the [grace period](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288559/3697633)

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm working backwards. I'm overcomplicating things, it makes more sense to just calculate i modulo the length of the alphabet, instead of calculating 26 modulo the position of the letter and then subtracting that from the offset.

Also, I didn't realize the else branch in encoder was doing exactly the same. Thanks for pointing that out. I got rid of the second if statement completely, it wasn't necessary and just redundant. And yes, you did see that line but I caught it right after posting, fixed it, and then realized the encoder function wasnt needed for this post.